# Why does this RuleDelayed behave weird?

Tags: functions, function-construction

This is something that I couldn't explain.

```
functions = {ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2 x], x >= 1 || x <= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x >= 0]};
```

My first function has two separate branches.

```
Plot[ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2 x], x >= 1 || x <= 0], {x, -5, 
  5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Now assume that I want to combine all lines into one `Line` head like this and plot it with ListLinePlot. 
 As you can see in the image, it has only one branch.

```
ListLinePlot @@ 
 Cases[Plot[functions[[1]], {x, -5, 5}][[1]], {_Directive, l__Line} :>
     If[Length@{l} == 1, l, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All][[1]]
```

[image]

However, if I modify a bit and use `{l}` in the `If` function (not correct though) then it works for the first function and the image shows two branches.

```
ListLinePlot @@ 
 Cases[Plot[functions[[1]], {x, -5, 5}][[1]], {_Directive, l__Line} :>
     If[Length@{l} == 1, {l}, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All][[1]]
```

[image]

Why does it behave like this?
 Did I miss something or a bug?
I'm using version 12.2.0.0 (windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler example that replicates what you are seeing:

```
input1 = {Directive[blah], Line[foo], Line[bar]}

Cases[input1, 
 {_Directive, l__Line} :> If[Length@{l} == 1, l, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All][[1]]
```

> ```
> Line[bar]
> ```

```
Cases[input1,
  {_Directive, l__Line} :> If[Length@{l} == 1, {l}, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All][[1]]
```

> ```
> Line[{foo, bar}]
> ```

The reason we are getting `Line[bar]` in the first case above is: When we use `l` in the second argument of `If` we are actually using a four-argument form of `If` where

> If[condition,t,f,u] *gives* u *if* condition *evaluates to neither* True
> *nor* False.

Wrap `If[...]` with `HoldForm` to see what expression is processed on the rhs of `RuleDelayed` in the first case above:

```
Cases[input1, {_Directive, l__Line} :> 
  HoldForm[If[Length@{l} == 1, l, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]]], All]
```

[image]

As an other illustration try a modified input that triggers an error message:

```
input2 = {Directive[blah], Line[foo], Line[bar], Line[buz]}; 

Cases[input2, 
  {_Directive, l__Line} :> If[Length@{l} == 1, l, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All][[1]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how can I make `If` behave as 3-arguments? How about `HoldForm[l]`? It works here but I'm not sure if that is the way to go. Aslo just curious why does it look like a dot in your `Out[]` instead of a number?

Comment: You can use `If[Length@{l} == 1,First@{l}, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]]` instead of `If[Length@{l} == 1, l, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]]`. Re `Out[ ]`, it happens when I use `Edit >> Copy As >> Bitmap`  ( don't know why.)

Comment: Nice, I have never used copy Bitmap like that.